# loading a html page into modal using html5

Tags: javascript, html

I had a requirement to load a topology diagram by taking few html form fields as input. I was initially using the window.open() method to show the topology diagram in a new window. But this is old fashioned, and I want to use modal instead. I had used below code to pass some data to the new window

```
window.opener.document.getElementById("sample-xml").value;
```

but now if I am using modal, can anyone tell me how do I fit in the other html page into the modal and at the same time pass few values from the parent html page to the child html page..

I tried using < dialog > tag but it's supported only on chrome.

Comment: Could use an absolute iframe with zindex and layer it above the rest with height/width 90%. Mostly gives a nice effect for such stuff and has a wide support.

Comment: "But this is old fashioned". Maybe, maybe not. If your topology diagram is something that enhances the experience on the parent page, a new window or tab is a better experience, as it allows the user to move the diagram around the desktop to view both the original page and the diagram simultaneously.